# product list filtering by checkboxes without Javascript enabled

Tags: php, yii

I am using YII and I have a checkbox filter that filters Product by Brands.

This is my filter HTML:

```
<dl class="brand-filter"> 
    <dd class="cat-text">  
        <input value="1" id="chb_1" class="brand-filter-chb" type="checkbox" name="brands[]">            
        <label for="chb_1" class="brand-filter-text" style=" display: inline-block;">Brand Name 1</label>      
    </dd>
    <dd class="cat-text">          
        <input value="2" id="chb_2" class="brand-filter-chb" type="checkbox" name="brands[]">            
        <label for="chb_2" class="brand-filter-text" style=" display: inline-block;">BRAND Name 2 </label>
    </dd>
    etc.
</dl>
```

When user does a click on checkbox then jquery do YII fn.yiiListView.update. This is something like ajax call that updates data I am filtering. Ajax call is made to controller/action (in my case controller is Product and action is List) and parameter $brands is passed to controller/action.

This is my filter javascript (Jquery):

```
$('.brand-filter-chb').live('click', function(){        
    brands = $('#filter-form').serialize();     //brand names are serialized 
    $.fn.yiiListView.update(  //this updates product list by brand names
        'product-list',   //id of product list table
        {data: brands}   //serialized data send to controller/action by ajax call
    );    
});
```

This allows to filter Product list by brands. Use checks Brand Name checkbox and list is filtered. Also user can check more than one Brand Name and everything works fine.
However, it doesn't work without Javascript.

I wondering what is the best solution to allow the same or very similar user experience without javascript.
For example, it would be also acceptable if use could filter Product list only by one Brand if javascript is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

What i'd suggest is to enclose your filter HTML within a form and set the action of the form to the same action you used for your AJAX filter.

If you're considering SEO, then your form should submit using the get method and then you can use Yii's request object:

`Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest`

to determine if it's the AJAX request that's being processed or the Non-script version.

You can enclose the submit button for the form filter within a couple of  tags.

As for knowing what checkboxes were selected before reloading a page, I'm not entirely sure it's possible without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wanting to use javascript, what you could do is create a

`<noscript>Please enable javascript</noscript>`

or have the page refresh after a check box is selected and do the showing / hiding of the elements with your php.

Comment: This is not my case. I want user to allow use my page also without Javascript. I need a page running without Javascript for better SEO (I need Google to find possibility to filter products by brands. At least I think that this is necessary.). How can I refresh a page when check box is selecting and remember what was checked (without javascript)?

Comment: That isn't how SEO works. You should research SEO. Almost all sites use JS and have good SEO. You will either need them to click a submit button to submit the form to PHP or use javascript as an onClick event to submit the form.

Comment: Oups. I meant that this checkbox filter update is done by Ajax and Ajax usually is not SEO friendly... So I will probably use javascript onClick for checkboxes.

Comment: ahh ok, or what you can do which is what alot of companies do is use PHP to parse all possible checkbox filter solutions and add them into the `<head><meta>` tags. This is SEO friendly.